# Store a function in MongoDB in Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

Is it possible to store a function in a MongoDB collection in Meteor?

I have tried defining my schema with

```
const SchemaName = new SimpleSchema({
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  transform: {
    type: Function,
  }
});

CollectionName.attachSchema(SchemaName);
```

and add a document with

```
CollectionName.insert({ text: "Some text", transform: function (value) { return value * 2; } });
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I saved function as type "String" and then during loading, I convert it into function by using `eval` or `new Function()`. `Function` is not a type in `SimpleScheme`

Comment: Now you've got to be really careful with the source of that function since otherwise this will become an ideal attack vector.

Comment: yes, the saved function is for the form builder we made for internal usage, thus it is under control

Comment: So it's simply not possible to save a function to a collection? How can I then obtain what I want? Should I just have some pre-defined functions in my code, and then save the function name in the collection instead of saving the entire function?